Sitecore Images missing from CD Page after SSO Renewal
We have a Sitecore 9 project running on .NET Framework and it uses Kentor authentication for SSO. After renewing the SAML metadata and certificate, the images on our page have stopped displaying. They're still in the Media Library on our CM instance and they can be accessed via direct URL on CM, but on the CD they're missing and accessing via direct URL gives returns a 404 error instead.
The metadata and certificate have been updated on both CM and CD instances and I can't think of anything else that needs to be done. If anyone could help share some ideas on this, I'd be very grateful.
Tried:

accessing image via direct URL
updating SAML on both CM and CD instances

